# Is it possible to control instances count for a concurrent quarz job

Tags: grails, quartz

I have a quartz job with

```
static concurrent = true
```

and see that it might be N instances at the same time (for me N=11)

The question here is it possible to limit concurrent instances exactly for this job (not for all by using quartz.threadPool.threadCount) count via configuration or any other easy way (e.g. N=2)?

ENV: org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.12, grails 3.1.16